# How to have images that do not resize when zooming in a UIScrollView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ipad

I want to have images inside of a UIScrollView (or at least *appear* to be inside a UIScrollView) that don't change their size when zooming in and out.  I do want the images to maintain their positions when zooming or scrolling.

The use case is that I have a customized map view with pushpins.  I want the pushpins to stay in place when zooming and scrolling the map, but I don't want them to be "zoomed in" with the content.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have your pushpin image(s) as a subview of your UIScrollView but not a subview of the view returned by

```
- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
```

Then, in scrollViewDidZoom adjust the pushpin x and y by the zoomScale to keep the pins correctly positioned:

```
- (void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
    imageView.frame = CGRectMake(pushPinX * scrollView.zoomScale, pushPinY * scrollView.zoomScale, imageView.frame.size.width, imageView.frame.size.height);
}
```

Comment: This almost did it for me.  Instead of repositioning my pins in scrollViewDidZoom I do it in scrollViewDidScroll which gets called continuously as view is zooming.  Thanks for the tip!